# Uni-directinal OneToOne mapping vs Bi-directinal OneToOne mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am working with hibernate mapping,when I implemented OneToOne bi-directional mapping,in the inverse side there is no column created to refer the owning side.

These are the classes I used,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Address121_2")
public class Address {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int addressId;
private String city;


@OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")

private Employee employee;


public int getAddressId() {
    return addressId;
}


public void setAddressId(int addressId) {
    this.addressId = addressId;
}


public String getCity() {
    return city;
}


public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}


public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}


public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Address [addressId=" + addressId + ", city=" + city + ", employee=" + employee + "]";
}
```

}

The other one,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="emp121_2")
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int employeeId;  
private String name;
private String email; 

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="a_id")
private Address address;


public int getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId;
}
public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [employeeId=" + employeeId + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + ", address=" + address
            + "]";
}
```

}

So without having reference from inverse side to owning side,what is the use of having bi directional mapping?

Comment: Wait... title is about OneToOne but i only see OneToMany and ManyToOne in the entities you provided... so which one is it?

Comment: sorry I posted the correct ones now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference is that bidirectional will give you navigational access in both directions.
That means you can get the other side of the relation without querying.

Also it allows for cascading option (careful with them in a `@OneToMany` regarding performance).

There will be no difference in the database between uni- or bi-directional.

Comment: But without having the reference in the database(for the owning side),how will the navigation access actually work

Comment: The owning side will have the column with the FK. That js what the joinColumn annotation is for. The pther side with mappedBy is just to make navigation in java object easier

Comment: But the same thing is also done by uni directional mapping,so what is the extra need for the bi directional mapping

Comment: @Gowtham Parimi Lets go with an example: you have gotten an Address object via query, now you want to get the corresponding Employee. 2 options. 1- you get the Employee via query, 2- You have a bidirectional relation and access it via field (address.getEmployee()). With unidirectional you don't have the extra field for navigation parent-->child in java.

Comment: Thanks,now my doubt got cleared.I totally ignored the java classes and only trying to find the relation between the tables created in both directions.